Padding to a specific level and adding character at the end
I have a text file:
a
aaa
aaa
a

My desired outcome is:
a                               N
aaa                             N
aaa                             N
a                               N

I wrote the following:
newf=""
with open('testfile.txt','r') as f:
   for line in f:
     if len(line) < 87:
         newf+=line.strip()+" "
     else:
        newf+=line.strip()+"N\n"
   f.close()
with open('testfile.txt','w') as f:
  f.write(newf)
  f.close()

When I run this, my outcome becomes:
a aaa aaa a
I can't figure out why it changes the output to one line.

So if the line itself is bigger than the padding, you just want to add "N" at the end? no matter if it doesn't align ?

Do you want the padding calculated programmatically or hard coded?

I need the N to align at the same spot at the end of each line and hard code it in.

Then what should happen if you have a line like "a" * 100 ?

I am adding the N the original text file I am needing this for is a bank file with set characters and no N at the end.

the file I get is the same characters for each line but the characters change so the file would like something like this:                                                           aaaa                                                                          a                                                                                aaa                                                                            aaaaaaaaaa                                                 hard to format each think of the a as its own seperate line and it requires N at character 88

Several tangential errors were pointed out to you the first time you tried to ask; did you not read those comments?

@PatrickPerea You haven't explained what should happen if the data that would precede N has 88 or more characters

BTW it's not necessary to do f.close() within a whit statement.

No data would precede the N like my example it would be data spaces to equal to 87 and N on space 88.  I did get it solved Thank you everybody, just looking how to mark it as solved.

You can consider f-strings to help you do the formatting.
def reformat_file(filename, desired_length=87, suffix='N'):
    lines = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = line.strip()
            formatted = line
            if len(line) < desired_length:
                formatted = f"{line:{desired_length}}{suffix}"

            lines.append(formatted)

    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('\n'.join(lines))

    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reformat_file("testfile.txt")

Running reformat_file where testfile.txt contains the below
a
aaa
aaa
a
a really long line that will have more than the threshold number of characters is written here.
abc

Will rewrite overwrite testfile.txt with the following.
a                                                                                      N
aaa                                                                                    N
aaa                                                                                    N
a                                                                                      N
a really long line that will have more than the threshold number of characters is written here.
abc                                                                                    N


I got it to work and to work with the real files, thank you.

It's changing it to one line because it is only seeing the following code which says just add a space between them.
newf+=line.strip()+" "

If you would like your desired outcome you would change the above to something like the following
newf+=line.strip()+"\t\t\t\t\tN\n"

adjust for how many tabs you would like for your desired spacing.

the easiest is just f-string
for line in f:
    if len(line) < 87:
        print(f'{line:<87}N')
    else:
        line = list(line)
        line[87] = 'N'
        print(''.join(line))


...but this does not modify the input file which I believe is a requirement

If reading the entire file contents into memory is not an issue (RAM constraints) and if no lines exceed the 88-character width constraint then:
with open("testfile.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = list(map(str.rstrip, f))
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(f"{line:<88}N\n")
    f.truncate()

The constant 88 might possibly be 87 depending on where position 88 is considered to be in the line (offset 0 or 1)
